# Add Permission-Attribute to Swashbucke-Swagger-Documentation

Tags: .net, swagger, swashbuckle

Having Swashbuckle integrated in my .Net Web-Api project (.Net Framework 4) I'm searching for a way to document the roles that are allowed to execute a respective method.

Each of my web-api methods have a custom attribute that checks the ActiveDirectory-Group of the requesting user and if the user is allowed to execute the action. But now I would like to document that using Swashbuckle-Swagger like

```
///
///<AllowedRole>Administrator</AllowedRole>
///
public IHttpActionResult Index(){
...
}
```

Or

```
[SwaggerAllowedRole("Administrator")]
public IHttpActionResult Index(){
    ...
}
```

I would love to hear that there is any standard that I can use.
Can anyone give me a clever trick?

Comment: I think the XML option (///) is a good idea, and it supports markup, ...but read on the OpenAPI-Specification see if you can find a better fit: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md

Comment: Here is an example of what you can do with the XML documentation: http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Location#/Location/Location_Get2

Comment: @HelderSepu: Can you give me an example? Adding a Tag to the xml, this tag is included in the xml-file but is not considered calling the swagger-ui respectively calling the xml in swagger (../swagger/docs/v1) :(

Comment: I did give you an example... the code behind that is https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/blob/master/Swagger_Test/Controllers/ApiExplorerController.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, I solved the problem using the "venderExtension" attribute.
I created an "SwaggerGroups"-Attribute:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
 public class SwaggerGroupsAttribute : Attribute
 {
     public SwaggerGroupsAttribute(params string[] groups)
     {
         this.Groups = groups;
     }
     public IEnumerable<string> Groups{ get; }
 }
```

And an operation filter that reads the attributes and adds the list to the *vendorExtension*:

```
 public class GroupPermission: IOperationFilter
 {

        public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
        {
            var attributes = apiDescription.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<SwaggerGroupsAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
            if (attributes == null) return;

            if(operation.vendorExtensions == null) operation.vendorExtensions = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            var permissionList = new List<string>();
            foreach(var permission in attributes.Permissions)
            {
                permissionList.Add(permission);
            }
            operation.vendorExtensions.Add("someKey", permissionList);
        }
    }
```

With this setup I can define the allowed roles as follows:

```
[SwaggerGroups("Administrator")]
public IHttpActionResult Index(){
    ...
}
```